# read the data from text file in QT

Tags: c++, qt, file

I have to read the data from text file in QT which has data in this form

> 1      1
>   2      4
>   3      9
>   4      16
>   5      25

I would like to take every integer or float number  and assign it to a array variable like

```
X[0]=1, Y[0]=1 & 
X[1]=2, Y[1]=4  and so on....  

enter code here
QString filename=QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"), "media://", "All files (*.*);; Text File (*.txt)");

QFile file3(filename);

if(!file3.open(QFile::ReadOnly|QFile::Text))
QMessageBox::information(0,"info", file3.errorString());


QTextStream in3(&file3);

QString xv,*p,xx,yy;

QStringList L;

for(j=0;j<n;j++)
{
 xv = in3.readLine();
 p[0]=xv;
 p[1]=xv;
 xx=p[0];
 yy=p[1];

 L=xx.split(" ");

 L=yy.split(" ");

 X[j]=L[0].toFloat();

 ui->xvalue->addItem(QString::number((X[j])));

 xv.split(" ", QString::SkipEmptyParts);

 Y[j]=L[1].toFloat();

 ui->yvalue->addItem(QString::number((Y[j])));

 }`
```

I tried many ways but nothing worked for me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have formatted your data using > at the start and adding two spaces at end of each line.  And I formatted your code using four leading spaces.  PLease edit the post and show us your code so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!file3.open(QFile::ReadOnly|QFile::Text)){
    QMessageBox::information(0,"info", file3.errorString());
```

That's bad, you need to handle the error wit more than a messagebox, or enclose to the rest in an else statement.

```
*p
```

Why is one of those strings a pointer?

```
for(j=0;j<n;j++)
```

you haven't declared n.. does this even compile?

```
X[j]=L[0].toFloat();
```

Why are you incrementing your array by the j iterator?  You are going to get a memory error immediately because you will never have more than [1] since you only have a single split per line with 2 floats per line.  You really only need to access [0] and [1]

Just in general you need to use containers and memory safe code, not raw arrays.  Plus I may be lost in your fun variable naming but why convert it to a float, then convert it right back into a QString?  Just plug it straight into your ui element.

```
while (!file.atEnd()) {
    QString line = in.readLine();
    QStringList list = line.split(" ");
       ui->xvalue->addItem(line[0]);
       ui->xvalue->addItem(line[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Your logic is useful, but problem is I could able to read only 1st line
      if(!file3.open(QFile::ReadOnly|QFile::Text))
      QMessageBox::information(0,"info", file3.errorString());
 
        else { QTextStream in3(&file3);
         while (file3.atEnd()) {
    QString line = in3.readLine();

        QStringList list = line.split(" ");

        ui->xvalue->addItem((list[0]);
        ui->yvalue->addItem(list[1]);

}}

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use `QTextStream`

```
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>

QFile f("your.file");
f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QTextStream s(&f);

while ( !s.atEnd() ) {
  double d;
  s >> d;
  // append d to some list;
}
```